# How to share PDF files in flutter

Tags: flutter, pdf, dart

There does not appear to be any pub.dev plugin that allows sharing of PDF files.
My app creates PDFs.. I want to be able to share these PDFs.

So far, it seems that all these plugins only support sharing of PNG's..

How should I share my PDF?

Comment: Check this: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_share

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've used package [esys_flutter_share](https://pub.dev/packages/esys_flutter_share)

```
var sharePdf = await file.readAsBytes();
await Share.file(
  'PDF Document',
  'project.pdf',
  sharePdf.buffer.asUint8List(),
  '*/*',
);
```

Comment: Yes.. this plugin works with PDFs. Thank you very very much,. You've just increased the value of my app from 0.0 to 0.10 cents. I'd love to know how I can make money with Flutter.. I'm working so hard and earning so few

Comment: no null safety. now not working

Answer (score 0):

I finally achieved it by using the below package as esys_flutter_share  no null safety.

```
  path_provider: ^2.0.12
  share_plus: ^6.3.1
  screenshot: ^1.3.0
```

---

First creating the function==> **widget to pdf**

```
class _MyGoalDetailsState extends State<MyGoalDetails> {
   List<GlobalKey> printKey = List<GlobalKey>.generate(100, (index) => GlobalKey(debugLabel: 'key_$index'),growable: false);
  final doc = pw.Document();
    // ========== Funtion() for widget to pdf ============
void _printScreen(int index) async {
  final image = await WidgetWraper.fromKey(
    key: printKey[index],
    pixelRatio: 2.0,
  );

  final directory = await getTemporaryDirectory();
  final file = File('${directory.path}/my_goal.pdf');
  
  final pdf = pw.Document();
  pdf.addPage(pw.Page(
    build: (pw.Context context) {
      return pw.Center(
        child: pw.Image(image),
      );
    },
  ));
  
  await file.writeAsBytes(await pdf.save());

  await Share.shareFiles(
    [file.path],
    text: 'Check out my goal details',
    subject: 'My goal details',
  );
}
......................................
...................
```

Then wrap the widget which I want to pdf.

```
 RepaintBoundary(
                key: printKey[0],
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.white,
                     padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15,15,15,0),
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [.................................
```

And onPress of my share button creating my pdf..

```
 IconButton(
        onPressed: () async {
                              _printScreen(0);
                            },
        icon: const Icon(Icons.share),
      ),
```